# Как восстановить виртуальную машину Oracle VM VirtualBox

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

Хочу делать резервные копии с возможностью полностью восстановить виртуалку.

Но не могу понять, что нужно копировать на другой носитель и как потом это восстановить, и возможно ли это?

Вот:

```
   cd VirtualBox VMs/scout_data:
   ls
  - scout_data.vbox
  - Snapshots
  - scout_data_20190325-disk001.vmdk
  - scout_data.vbox-prev
```

Comment: Там есть возможность сделать экспорт виртуалки в файл *.ova или *.ovf. И затем можно импортировать этот же файл.

Comment: @Bogdan, а если я допустим один раз сделаю экспорт, и каждый день буду новые снимки делать и копировать в другое место, то потом по файлу экспорта и снимкам получится восстановить последнее состояние машины?